# AADB2C Exception

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

We are developing a mobile client App that is working with the MSAL library to login through Azure. Today we started getting this exception on the client side for both Android and iOS:

[image]

Same thing happens if I try to hit the login url through desktop:

[image]

This is from the WebView that the [MSAL library](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android) uses. Everything was working perfectly a couple of days ago and out of nowhere this exception started popping up.

Another thing is that we can actually login and use the App normally if we tunnel through a VPN and go through a United States/Canadian network. If we do that everything works perfectly. But if we try to connect from outside the US or Canada we get this exception. The people in charge of the Azure account told us that they didn't change anything this last days.

I was hoping that maybe you guys can point us in the right direction to dig the cause of this issue. I'm not looking for a straight answer, I know that this is a kinda tricky issue, but any tip that could lead me to detect the issue It's appreciated.

Thanks, and let me know if I can provide any other information.

Comment: which version of MSAL are you using?

Comment: @Jenny The 0.2.1, isn't the latest one, since they release a new version a couple of weeks ago. But I highly doubt that this is something related to the MSAL library, since that on desktop is happening the same thing. I'm trying to figure out what could had happened that only affects some countries.